# "Missing host to link to!" for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I installed Devise and things seem to stop up whenever I try to create an account.

The full error reads:

`Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]`

I've got the following code sitting in inside the development.rb block.  I've tried it with and without the added smtp configurations.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }  
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
...
```

Have I defined `host` incorrectly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The files under config/ are not automatically reloaded in development. If you have made changes to this file, ensure that you have restarted the Rails server, and any Rails console sessions for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I had to restart Unicorn too.

Answer (score 4):

### Inherit your Application's `default_url_options` from `ActionMailer`.

By default, the `default_url_options` that you set for `config.action_mailer` in your environment files (`development.rb`, `production.rb`, etc.) do not get used as the `default_url_options` of your `Application` as a whole.

```
$ MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}

$ MyApp::Application.default_url_options
#=> {}
```

So, when you try and use anything that requires the host and port (e.g. url) outside of the mailer, it doesn't know what to do.

You can solve this by hard coding the host and port in multiple places for the same environment, but you don't want to do that unless your `ActionMailer` *actually* uses a different host and port than the rest of your `Application`.

To solve this (and keep things as DRY as possible), you can automatically use the `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` as your entire `Application`'s `default_url_options`.

Simply add the following line to your `config/environment.rb` file (changing `MyApp` to your app's name):

```
# Set the default host and port to be the same as Action Mailer.
MyApp::Application.default_url_options = MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

This will fix your problem and automatically set your `Application`'s `default_url_options` to the same as your `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`:

```
$ MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}

$ MyApp::Application.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting it dynamically solved the problem.

```
  # application_controller.rb
  before_filter :mailer_set_url_options

  ...

  def mailer_set_url_options
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
  end
```

I realize this configuration doesn't belong in a controller by convention, but for development purposes it seems to suffice. I can always code it into into the production environment configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Add to the end of file`config/environment.rb` line:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'yourhost.com'
```

It is not only problem in `action_mailer`, but also setting default host for the `routes` as well.