# Rails: Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have been googling for about 90 minutes now and still don't have an answer to this.  Where do I set `default_url_options`?  I've already set it for `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` to solve this same bug elsewhere, but now I'm getting this error when trying to use a URL helper inside an RSpec spec.  I have no idea where it's expecting default_url_options to be set.

```
 Failure/Error: listing_url(listing).should match(/\/\d+-\w+$/)
 RuntimeError:
   Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]
 # ./spec/routing/listing_routing_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This code has nothing to do with emails/ActionMailer, it just happens to need a URL instead of a path.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the host anyway?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
Your::Application.routes.draw do
  default_url_options :host => "example.com"

  # ... snip ...
end
```

Somewhere in `routes.rb` :)

Comment: Not very good if you've got many different environments with differing URLs

Comment: Yeah what do you do if you have multiple env domains?

Comment: Presumably you just specify it for each URL instead, either in the route map, or in the url helper invocation: `listing_url(listing, :host => "whatever.com")`.

Comment: In the config file for each respective environment, I add this custom option: `config.domain = 'staging.myapp.com'` (of course substitute in a correct domain name for each env). Then in `routes.rb` I'm free to use `default_url_options host: Rails.application.config.domain` and it will work in any environment. You're welcome.

Comment: A better approach would be to, within the routes file, do this: `default_url_options Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options`.

Answer (score 304):

You need to add the following line at every environment:

**`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "yourhost" }`**

That way, it can work in all environments and could be different from environment to environment. For example:

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "dev.yourhost.com" }
```

**test.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "test.yourhost.com" }
```

**production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "www.yourhost.com" }
```

Comment: Also make sure that you restart your rails server after you add this.  The files under config/ are not automatically reloaded.

Comment: I have done very similar to this and setting the default_url_option for action_mailer won't help.

The use case is similar to this:
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.message_image_url(2)

Comment: Did this; with or without www... prefixing the host name in production, I still got the same error.  Added the route per @d11wtq, and it worked.  Is there some Rails4 change that caused this behavior?  I never saw it before the upgrade, and only in one particular mail-send (devise-automated), since.

Comment: Can confirm that this does not work in my Rails 4 projects. Setting it in routes is simply no option.

Comment: Why does this error happen anyway? What is host: in the solution? What does that do?

Comment: Not working in Rails 5.  Added `default_url_options Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options` though and that did the trick, as suggested by another commenter

Answer (score 47):

The host should be specified in each environment's config file. Eg:

```
config/environments/development.rb
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366746/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-default-url-optio) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638949/missing-host-to-link-to-for-devise).

Comment: Thanks, IMHO this is a better answer than the answer that uses routes.draw

Comment: This answer does not help when using different domains and addresses other problems.

Comment: @Ryan you can just use environment vars to fix that

Answer (score 46):

#### Set `default_url_options` to use your `action_mailer.default_url_options`.

In each of your environment files (e.g. `development.rb`, `production.rb`, etc.) you can specify the `default_url_options` to use for `action_mailer`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'lvh.me', port: '3000' }
```

However, these are not set for `MyApp:Application.default_url_options`:

```
$ MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}

$ MyApp::Application.default_url_options
#=> {}
```

That's why you are getting that error in anything outside of `ActionMailer`.

You can set your Application's `default_url_options` to use what you defined for `action_mailer` in the appropriate environment file (`development.rb`, `production.rb`, etc.).

To keep things as DRY as possible, do this in your `config/environment.rb` file so you only have to do this once:

```
# Initialize the rails application
MyApp::Application.initialize!

# Set the default host and port to be the same as Action Mailer.
MyApp::Application.default_url_options = MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

Now when you boot up your app, your entire Application's `default_url_options` will match your `action_mailer.default_url_options`:

```
$ MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}

$ MyApp::Application.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}
```

*Hat tip to [@pduersteler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16490021/293280) for leading me down this path.*

Comment: Setting up the `config/environment.rb` as you described was the key for getting my mailer to work in the console. Thank you!

Comment: @EricD.Fields You're very welcome, Eric! I find this so useful that I think it should be built into the Rails core.

Comment: That would be `Rails.application.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options` for Rails 5.2+

Comment: Thanks, @SandroL! We're still on Rails 4.2 so haven't tested yet on later versions.

Comment: A few people recommending this.  I guess it's just that people tend to have action_mailer.default_url_options already configured for historical reasons, but isn't it more logical to set _that_ based on application.default_url_options rather than the other way around? Why involve a bogus mailer reference when configuring how your website links work?

Comment: @HarryWood I would agree, but for those of us that have been around since Rails 2, it began with `action_mailer` and so that's where our typical host and port configuration is stored.

Answer (score 25):

When you use any `listing_url` method the full URL will be returned(not a relative one as normal). That's why rails is asking you for the host, to compute the whole URL.

How you can tell rails the host? You can do it in several ways:

**1.Adding this option to each environment:**

```
[/config/development.rb]
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
[/config/test.rb]
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
[/config/production.rb]
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "www.example.com" }
```

**NOTE:** If you are working inside a *rails engine* remember to do the same for your dummy app inside the engine tests: `path_to_your_engine/test/dummy/config/environments/*` because when you test the engine it's what rails is testing against.

**2.Add the host option to the foo_url method like this:**

```
listing_url(listing, host: request.host) # => 'http://localhost:3000/listings/1'
```

**3.Not output the host with the option `:only_path to true`**.

```
listing_url(listing, only_path: true ) # => '/listings/1'
```

IMHO I don't see the point on this one because in this case I would use the `listing_path` method

Comment: Step 1 always works for me and today, using the refinery-cms gem just step 2 save me. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Very useful answer because of mentioning the scenario when you are working with a rails engine! 
In my case I ran into the error when trying to execute a rake task that was using a model inside an engine. I loaded my action_mailer config into the engine like this and was finally able to run the task.
`MyEngine::Engine.config.action_mailer.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options`
`MyEngine::Engine.routes.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options`

Answer (score 20):

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'`

In the developemnt.rb / test.rb, can be more concise as following:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... other config ...

  routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
end
```

Answer (score 16):

Funny thing, that setting `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` does not help for me. Also, messing around with environment-independent settings in places I felt like it does not belong was not satisfying for me. Additionally, I wanted a solution that worked when generating urls in sidekiq/resque workers.

My approach so far, which goes into `config/environments/{development, production}.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
    # Stuff omitted...

    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      # Set things here as usual
    }
end

MyApp::Application.default_url_options = MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

This works for me in rails >= 3.2.x.

Comment: This and only this worked for getting the mailer to include the URL, but it breaks other link_to functions in my app.

Comment: Great thinking, @pduesteler! I actually took this one step further and was able to add just one line in the `config/environment.rb` file to do this. And added answer that goes into detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529627/293280 Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 8):

You can always pass host as a parameter to the URL helper:

```
listing_url(listing, host: request.host)
```

Comment: Note:  You can add a port also `listing_url(listing, host: request.host, port: 3000)`

Comment: But what if you don't have the request context? Like in most things other than a controller?

Answer (score 8):

The above answer did not work for me, at least not as I wanted. 
I realised 
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost", port: 3000 }`
after installing devise.
Hope it will help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

go to config/environments/test.rb

Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'

Comment: Answer needs more information. Please describe what it is you're actually proposing as the solution.

Comment: Here are some useful tips on [answer]. I find them useful to refer to.

Answer (score 4):

just in case someone finds this searching for errors concerning ActiveStorage:

if you have a controller-action where you want to generate upload-urls etc with the local disc-service (most likely in test environment), you need to `include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent` in the controller in order to allow `blob.service_url_for_direct_upload` to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Using this outside of a controller (GraphQL direct upload mutation) so had to tweak it a bit, but works. I've been looking for this, thanks again @phoet :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set default url options in the Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    {:locale => I18n.locale}
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default_url_options

Comment: This is a good solution for Rails 4, because it lets you set options specific to a controller if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error. I had everything written in correctly, including the Listing 10.13 from the tutorial.

```
Rails.application.configure do
.
.
.
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delevery_method :test
host = 'example.com'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
.
.
.
end
```

obviously with "example.com" replaced with my server url.

What I had glossed over in the tutorial was this line:

> After **restarting the development server** to activate the configuration...

So the answer for me was to turn the server off and back on again.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the default_url in routes not the right solution although, it works for some cases.

You've to set the default_url in each environment(development, test, production).

You need make these changes.

```
    config/environments/development.rb
     config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'

 config/environments/test.rb
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'

  config/environments/development.rb
     config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by configuring environment.rb as

YourApp::Application.default_url_options = YourApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options

You need to set default_url_options for action mailer against each environment like development, testing, staging and production etc.

Reference: [Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219732/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-default-url-optio/48529627#48529627)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want to change the behavior for other environments, so I used:

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
...
end

Rails.application.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

Works in Rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

#### `Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options`

```rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'my.domain', protocol: 'https', port: 356 }
```

#### `Rails.application.default_url_options`

```rb
self.default_url_options = config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

Firstly setup Action Mailer default url options (like in the most of the answers)

And after that assign that options to Application. Initial question is exactly about this config! Not about the mailer:) It is strange that question is old but not all answers setup this config and didn't mention simple `self` assignment

Put such lines into `config/application.rb` or into specific environment, for example into `config/environments/development.rb`

After that you can access to routes helpers like this

```rb
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_url(25)
# => "https://my.domain:356/users/25"
```