# Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host] (ActionView::Template::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I installed devise and added `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` to my development.rb file as suggested. When I run cucumber I get an error:

> Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set
>   default_url_options[:host] (ActionView::Template::Error)

does anyone know what this is related to? not too much info on google about this

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Cucumber runs your test environment so you need to add the very same line in `test.rb`.

Answer (score 12):

For posterity, in case it has nothing to do with mailers but you still get the `Missing host` error while running capybara, rspec...

If you are using url helpers in your tests and have included somewhere in your rspec config:

```
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Then, you should also add something along this line to the same config:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "test.host"
```

Comment: This is true. Ideally, you don't want to hard code the same host and port for the same environment, though. For a DRY solution, check out my answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529627/293280