# Rails 5.2 how to fix Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, active-model-serializers

Locally, it works. In `Heroku` production, I keep getting this error message when using `ActiveModelSerializers`. I've using `active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.2)`

> ArgumentError (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):

I've read through

- [Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host] (ActionView::Template::Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366746/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-default-url-optio)
- [Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, for Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131936/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-the-host-parameter-for-rails-4)

I've tried defining it in `./app/config/environments/production.rb`

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'lit-brushlands- 
 65490.herokuapp.com' }

end
```

I've tried defining it in  `./app/serializers/application_serializer.rb` like I see Drifting Ruby do it at 2:30 into the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ah5SaN1linA).

```
# ./app/serializers/application_serializer.rb
class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  default_url_options[:host] = 'lit-brushlands-65490.herokuapp.com'

end
```

I've also tried defining it in `./config/application.rb` like how Remear suggested to do it as the last comment on this [pull request](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/1550) of ActiveModelSerializers.

Here's my stack trace. I try fetching a users profile photo in a decorator.

[image]

```
2018-05-29T12:40:31.274554+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-29T12:40:31.274447 #4]  INFO -- : [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3] [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (1766.98ms)
2018-05-29T12:40:31.274941+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-29T12:40:31.274854 #4]  INFO -- : [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1877ms (ActiveRecord: 126.0ms)
2018-05-29T12:40:31.276753+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-29T12:40:31.276654 #4] FATAL -- : [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3]
2018-05-29T12:40:31.276834+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-29T12:40:31.276754 #4] FATAL -- : [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3] ArgumentError (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
2018-05-29T12:40:31.276923+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-29T12:40:31.276835 #4] FATAL -- : [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3]
2018-05-29T12:40:31.277014+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-29T12:40:31.276930 #4] FATAL -- : [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3] app/decorators/user_decorator.rb:13:in `most_recent_profile_photo'
2018-05-29T12:40:31.277017+00:00 app[web.1]: [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3] app/serializers/user_serializer.rb:11:in `profile_photo_url'
2018-05-29T12:40:31.277019+00:00 app[web.1]: [b70376bf-4950-4376-bf91-f21a3533e9d3] app/controllers/v1/posts_controller.rb:10:in `index
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: I added both a photo and a copy of it @JagdeepSingh

Comment: What does method `most_recent_profile_photo`?

Comment: It looks at the `User` model, grabs the most recent profile photo(a model which belongs to `User`, `Upload`), then looks at the URL of the attached uploaded media(their profile photo hosted to AWS).

https://gist.github.com/PrimeTimeTran/9924674dd2ea2f860d6b0e9b67ce3bd8

Comment: It works fine locally when I look at the JSON. https://imgur.com/a/D3TSqiV

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `carrierwave` with AWS. It's possible the error is not coming directly from `Serializer`, check your setttings for `carrierwave`

Maybe you are using different host in development and that needs change

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     'xxx',                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key: 'yyy',                        # required
    region:                'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    host:                  's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    endpoint:              'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                                   # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                                 # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.days.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Comment: I'm using ActiveStorage @Przemek

Answer (score 1):

I am not using `ActiveModelSerializers` but I had the same error but this did not solve it for me:

`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

I fixed it by updating my production environment file as follows:

```
# production.rb
```

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] ='lit-brushlands-65490.herokuapp.com'`

Comment: When you answer a technical question, it is important to provide narrative that explains why and how you chose your answer. For instance, how does your answer differ from what the original poster had in their question?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I choose that answer because I resolve same problem in my case. And the difference what I'm not using a `ActiveModel::Serializer`, so `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` doesn't work properly in my opinion. Does this answer satisfy you?