# Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

> Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set
>   default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

I randomly get this error at time, generally restarting the server fixes the issue for a while, and then it shows up again.
I have added 
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = "localhost:3000"`, in the development and test.rb files.

Also, I have used `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`
in one module to get access to the routes, I read this could be the reason I get these errors but removing it will leave me with no access to the routes.
The module is for the datatables gem.

Comment: What you ended up doing @raunak Joneja ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default\_url\_options\[:host\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219732/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-default-url-optio)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For Rails 5, use:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "XXX"
```

You can put this in a `config/environments/` file (or any other initializer), or e.g. at the beginning of `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: Where would you add that? In `config/environments/<env>.rb`?

Comment: You can use it wherever you see fit. It can be the environment files.

Usually, I end up with the same statement (reading the host value from an environment variable) and thus, I put this line at the top of `routes.rb` since it's the file defining/setting `Rails.application.routes`.

Answer (score 25):

You should write in the following way

For Development(development.rb)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

In production (production.rb)

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "myproductionsite.com" }
```

Comment: didn't work, changed action_mailer to controller, made the value a hash, checked my heroku console, same error: 'ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):' prod host: { :host => "myherokuapp.herokuapp.com" }

Comment: why do you change action_controller ?

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar error. The problem is in your configuration.

Try rewriting your configuration for your development.rb and test.rb like this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost", port: 3000 }
```

Also check that your configuration in production.rb is written correctly like this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myherokuapp.herokuapp.com' }
```

Answer (score 7):

You have updated the default url options for action mailer.
URL helpers will take the option from action_controller settings.

`config.action_controller.default_url_options = .....`

BR

Comment: Also, url options is a hash, not a string.

Comment: didn't work, changed action_mailer to controller, made the value a hash,

checked my heroku console, same error:

 'ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):'

prod host: { :host => "myherokuapp.herokuapp.com" }