# Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host]

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

Trying to preview my mailer in development, but I'm getting the above error.
(Using Michael Hartl Tutorial).

I believe it's not working because of my host. However, using cloud 9 I'm struggling to find what my host is. In the book it's defined as `host ='rails-tutorial-mhartl.c9users.io'` for the Cloud IDE, but this is unique to the book writer.

I tried using localhost, which hasn't worked and my dev url is different to whats in the book if this relates: `"..0.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"`

Essentially if I can find out my unique Cloud IDE host the problem  should get fixed, but I don't know where to locate this

development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true  
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test  
host = 'localhost:8080' 
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'http' }
```

account_activation.html.erb

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>

<p>
  Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
</p>

<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                                email: @user.email) %>
```

The page should load with the email preview, but full error message is:

> Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Rails 5, try this:

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "XXX"`

Found [this post about Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131936/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-the-host-parameter-for-rails-4/41336950) and there was a similar discussion in the Rails repository on [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32500)

Comment: Wow, great! Not sure how that worked, but it did - thank you

Comment: No worries. Did as you said, the above worked using the "XXX", but I've now updated the :host to match the root URL -  thanks will also look into the links in future to get more of an understanding

Comment: just change "XXX" to your root URL and it works. thanks