# Where to set host for Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a controller I call a service like:

```
MyService.call
```

In the `MyService.call` method I want to use a url helper:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.something_url
```

However, I get the error:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

in config/environments/development.rb I have:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
```

What should I set not to get the error?

Comment: Where is 'somewhere in the code'? Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219732/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-default-url-optio

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could set the host in the config files as:

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'your_host'`

This will set the default host not just for `action_mailer` and `action_controller`, but for anything using the `url_helpers`.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the doc where this is mentionned ? I often find references just for `action_mailer` but not the rest

Comment: Seems like this should go in the Rails.application.configure block somewhere?

Comment: As stated in this answer, much safer to set `routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'your_host'` as opposed to `routes.default_url_options = { host: 'your_host' }`. The latter will blow away any other options that were set.

Comment: Which file do you put this in? There are dozens of "config files".

Comment: `config/initializers/routes.rb` would be good place, I think.

Answer (score 12):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29992), whenever using route helpers, they don't defer `default_url_options` to `ActionMailer` or `ActionController` config and it is expected that there will be a `default_url_options` method in the class.  This worked for me:

```
class MyService
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def call
    something_url
  end

  class << self
    def default_url_options
      Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you can use `action_mailer` or `action_controller` config depending which you've configured.