# how pass url helper in model with :locale parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need pass in charge attributes in model contract_url(contract)
I have following code in model CheckoutService:

```
delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'

def contract_url(cont)
    url_helpers.contract_url(cont)
  end
```

In charge_attributes i need set url for attribute secureUrl, for example:

```
charge_attributes 
{
  secureReturnUrl: contract_url(contract)
}
```

I get an error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contracts", :locale=>#<Contract id: 13, ..} missing required keys: [:id]
```

rake routes:

**contract GET    (/:locale)/contracts/:id(.:format)                                                               contracts#show {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                                                                            PATCH  (/:locale)/contracts/:id(.:format)**

If i call this url helper in controller or view work correct.
How pass current locale in url in model? Thank you.

Comment: in any view if i call contract_path(@contract) work correct. Only problem with :local if i want call in model.

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter :locale to url. I18n.locale return current locale.

```
contact_url(contact, locale: I18n.locale)
```

Comment: ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219732/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-default-url-optio